# How do you dynamically update a snake in a Snake Game in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this has been asked already, but my code is a bit different than the usual snake code. I basically have some parts working already, which are:

- Generate and render the board
- Snake movement (with no eating and dying)
- Generate a fruit randomly inside the board
- Generate a fruit randomly again after being eaten

My issue now is to make the snake update and re-render itself inside the tick() every time it eats a fruit.

```
/**
 * @returns {TickReturn}
 */
tick() {

  // very simple movement code which assumes a single length snake
  // no eating or dieing implemented yet.

  let oldPosition = { ...this._snake[0]
  };

  switch (this._direction) {
    case Direction.Up:
      this._snake[0].y -= 1;
      break;
    case Direction.Down:
      this._snake[0].y += 1;
      break;
    case Direction.Left:
      this._snake[0].x -= 1;
      break;
    case Direction.Right:
      this._snake[0].x += 1;
      break;
  }

  if (this.eating(this._fruit)) {
    this._fruit = this.nextFruitFn(); // update the position of the fruit
    this.update(); // nothing's being done yet
  }

  return {
    gameOver: this._isGameOver,
    eating: false, // currently static, not doing anything yet
    changes: [{
        position: oldPosition,
        tileValue: Tiles.Empty
      },
      {
        position: this._snake[0],
        tileValue: Tiles.Snake
      },
      {
        position: this._fruit,
        tileValue: Tiles.Fruit
      }
    ]
  };
}

eating(pos) {
  let hasEaten = false;
  this._snake.map((s, idx) => {
    // if snake and position merged indices, 
    // then fruit has been eaten
    hasEaten = (s.y === pos.y && s.x === pos.x) ? true : false;
    if (hasEaten) {
      this._board[pos.x][pos.y] = Tiles.Empty;
      // make sure to clear the tile after eating
    }
  });

  return hasEaten;
}
```

I am lost with two things here:

- How do you update the snake array? Do you simply get the current x,y index and reduce both of them by 1? `{ y: y-1, x: x-1 }`?
- Once I successfully added the new array inside the snake, how do I properly render it in the `TickReturn` object? Currently, it is simply updating `this._snake[0]` at a position.
- How do I update the switch case that will include the succeeding parts of the snake? At the moment, it can only move itself fixed at `index 0`, like so:

  ```
  switch (this._direction) {
    case Direction.Up:
      this._snake[0].y -= 1;
      break;
    case Direction.Down:
      this._snake[0].y += 1;
      break;
    case Direction.Left:
      this._snake[0].x -= 1;
      break;
    case Direction.Right:
      this._snake[0].x += 1;
      break;
  }
  ```

Is this also a similar approach if I start considering the walls? Here's a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image]

Comment: Snippets are for runnable code, and neither of your snippets run. If you just wanted to show code, indent 4 spaces instead.

Comment: Done and updated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the snake become bigger as it eats? Push a new element in snake array with new coordinates accordingly with the last one.

Does the snake become smaller as it eats? Just remove the last element of snake array with splice: snake.splice( snake.length - 1, 1 ).

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: After pushing the new element, how do you render it again on the `tick()` function?